# django admin panel numbering every form in formset

Tags: python, django

how can i add numeration to every form in formset in django admin panel. I need next number for every new added form

```
class QuestionAnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = QuestionAnswer
    formset = SetTestQuestionAnswerFormSet
    fields = ('question_answer_text','right_mark')
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
                 ...
    ]
    inlines = [QuestionAnswerInline]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways to do that:

- Override edit view template for this specific admin class and add enumeration within template with {{ forloop.counter }}. This is probably easyest way of doing this
- Override formset class in your admin to provide counter for all the inline forms. You need to do quite abit of magic to achieve that, but that is also possible. Basically you extend the inline admin class get_formset method to create the forms, provide the counter data and then non-editable field to display that data.

Comment: thank you ! oh i tried second way yesterday it was too hard for me...it is works pretty well then i add new question. but it was displaying no data in filled forms...